# Mule scatter gather custom aggregation get message processor

Tags: java, mule, mule-component

Im using scatter gather with with custom AggregationStrategy. Where is several Web Service Consumers in this scatter gather. And i need to retrieve information about this consumers such as message processor name, original payload, outbound address, etc from events..

Something like that:

```
public class CustomAggregation implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public MuleEvent aggregate(AggregationContext context) throws MuleException {
        for (MuleEvent event : context.collectEventsWithoutExceptions()) {
            ...get message processor name from event...
            ...get message processor payload from event...
        }
        for (MuleEvent event : context.collectEventsWithExceptions()) {
            ...get message processor name from event...
            ...get message processor payload from event...
        }
    }
}
```

But i cant find anything about message processor in this events. How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

The message processor payload can be found in the MuleMessage of each MuleEvent (`event.getMessage().getPayload()`). I'm not sure about the message processor name or why you'd need that anyway, perhaps you could set a property or variable with the data needed in each route of the scatter-gather.
HTH

Comment: If there was an error then the MuleMessage will have an informative exception payload you can access via ```event.getMessage().getExceptionPayload()```.

Comment: Ye, but where is no information about which route fails.. I have several similar webservice consumers and i want to know which one fails. Like 
"An error has occurred at webservice with address ****". And i want to log successful responses too.

Comment: Have you tried with the message source? ```event.getMessageSourceName()```